# Deploy deletes all JEST Tests?

Tags: lwc-jest

I just upgraded VS Code (sfdx upgrade).  Now when I deploy my project:

sfdx force:source:deploy -x .\manifest\package.xml --verbose

All of the JEST test files are magically deleted from my local copy!  What's going on??  Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appear this issue was introduced in sfdx-cli 7.103.0. At this moment, the issue is still present in the latest RC (7.111.2). Reverting to version 7.102.0 worked for me.

I found more details about the issue in [this article](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/forcedotcom/cli/1044/860931892).

I hope this helps